# Why is * needed with pointers to arrays?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dereference

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x[][2] = { {1,2},{3,4},{5,6},{7,8} };
    int i, j;
    printf("%d \n", x);
    for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        printf("%u %u\n", x + i, *(x + i));
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= 1;j++)
        printf("%u %u\n", *(x + i + j), *(*(x + i) + j));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3217317712 3217317712
3217317720 3217317720
3217317728 3217317728
3217317736 3217317736
3217317712 1
3217317720 2
3217317720 3
3217317728 4
3217317728 5
3217317736 6
3217317736 7
3217317744 8
```

Now, when I'm printing `(x+i)` and `*(x+i)`, it is giving me the same result.
However, when I'm printing `*(x+i+j)` and `*(*(x+i)+j)`, it is giving me different results.
If `(x+i)` and `*(x+i)` are getting evaluated to the same value, why do I get different results in the second case?

Comment: You are printing pointers, but telling printf that they are integers. This is undefined bahaviour, and all sorts of strange things can happen then.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy formatting a pointer to integers will lose some bits in 64bit system.But this is not an undefined behavior.

Comment: @oyss: I do believe that giving inconsistent arguments to printf gives undefined behaviour. Quoting from (my free draft copy of) the standard (Committee Draft -- Septermber [sic] 7, 2007, page 280): "If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: Why is there no difference in (x+i) and *(x+i)?
I just don't understand it!

Comment: Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

The expressions **(x+i)** and ***(x+i)** are both pointers. They have different types, but they point to the same place in memory.

An attempt to write a longer answer:

When you use the name of an array in a C program, it is (with some exceptions) converted to a pointer to its first element. So if **a** is an array of integers, the name **a** will be converted to a pointer to an integer:

```
int a[3];
int *p = a; // Correct type
```

Your **x** is an array of arrays. When you use the name **x** in your program, it is converted to a pointer to its first element, which is an array, so you get a pointer to an array:

```
int x[][2] = { {1,2},{3,4},{5,6},{7,8} };
int (*p)[2] = x; // Correct type
```

So what happens when you add the pointer dereferencing operator, *****, to **x**? Remember that the expression **x** becomes a pointer to an array, so when you follow the pointer to the thing it points to, using ***x**, you get an array, in this case an array of two integers. But, as usual in C, that array expression is converted to a pointer to its first element, so you get a pointer to integer:

```
int *p2 = *x; // Correct type
```

But this pointer **p2** points to the same place in memory as the pointer **p** above. It's just their types that are different. **p** points to the first two-integer array, and **p2** points to the first integer in that array. That's the same place.

**x + i** just means "take the pointer **x** and step it **i** elements forward", not changing the type, so just like the expressions **x** and ***x** give pointers to the same place in memory, **(x + i)** and ***(x + i)** give pointers to the same place.

Note that **x** is an array of arrays, not an array of pointers to arrays, and that the expression **x** in your program gives a pointer to array, not a pointer to pointer. If **x** had been an array contaning pointers, the expression **x** would have given you a pointer to pointer, and in *that* case, **x** and ***x** would have been different.

Comment: @user3152736: What specifically are you thinking of there? The first four pointers in that example all point to the same place in memory, the start of the array of arrays **x**. The fifth pointer points to the variable **y**. The final thing you print is the number at the start of **x**.

Comment: "But, as usual in C, that array expression is converted to a pointer to its first element" Well, "usual" meaning in the context it's used in in this case, yes. But not in all cases.

Comment: @newacct: True, and that is why I wrote "with some exceptions". But it is probably important to note, for example, that with the **&** operator no conversion to pointer is made, so the expression **&x** doesn't first create a pointer, store it somewhere, and then create a new pointer to that place. Perhaps that was what user3152736 wondered in the comment above, why not just **x** and **\*x** but also **&x** point to the same place in memory?

Answer (score -1):

`x+i` and `*(x+i)` are all pointer types, just in first case it's `int**` and in second it's `int*` since it's pointer on array containing pointers on arrays. So the very right addressing is `*(*(x+i)+j)` and it will give you the number.

Comment: Be careful with the difference between pointers and arrays. There is no array containing pointers involved here! It's just an array of arrays, and the name of the array is converted to a pointer to array.

Comment: Yes, my bad, just checked it.

Comment: `x+1` isn't `int**`, it's `int (*)[4][2]`.

Comment: `x+i` isn't `int**`. It's `int (*)[2]`. and `*(x+i)` has type `int [2]`, an array type, not a pointer type, although it can be converted to a pointer type in some contexts.